# ASP.NET submit button RequiredFieldValidator not firing with Facebox

Tags: asp.net, facebox

I was trying to create a popup logon form for a site I'm working on so I decided to give facebox a try.  The logon pops up ok, but the submit button and required validators are not firing.  This is within the master page and is contained with a Progress Panel.

In the page header, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
    });
</script>
```

Towards the top of the form, I have this link:

```
<a href="#logon_form" rel="facebox">Logon</a>
```

Which is to open the layer listed below:

```
<div id="logon_form" style="display:none;">
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="centered">
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextLogonEmail" runat="server" CssClass="inputtext" ValidationGroup="LogonGroup" Columns="35" MaxLength="320"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredLogonEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextLogonEmail" ValidationGroup="LogonGroup" CssClass="error">required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextLogonPassword" runat="server" CssClass="inputtext" TextMode="Password" ValidationGroup="LogonGroup" Columns="35" MaxLength="40"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredLogonPassword" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextLogonPassword" ValidationGroup="LogonGroup" CssClass="error">required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2"><asp:Button ID="ButtonLogon" runat="server" Text="Logon" ValidationGroup="LogonGroup" onclick="ButtonLogon_Click" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Page.Validate("LogonGroup")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh.aspx), or if you want to call it using Javascript, try:

```
function myFunction(group)
 {
  if (Page_ClientValidate(group))
     { Something();       }
}
```

**--EDIT--**

You can provide that inside your `ButtonLogon_Click` event. Like,

```
Page.Validate("LogonGroup")
if(Page.IsValid())
{
    //Continue.
}
else
{
    ShowValidationSummary();
}
```

Ideally, your code should work. I would add the [`ValidationSummary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h%28VS.71%29.aspx) within your `LogonForm Div`. For instance like:

```
<div id="logon_form" style="display:none;">
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="centered">
     <tr>
            <td>
<asp:ValidationSummary id="LogonGroup" 
                             DisplayMode="BulletList"
                             EnableClientScript="true"
                             HeaderText="You must enter a value in the following fields:"
                             runat="server"/>
</td>
</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextLogonEmail" runat="server" CssClass="inputtext" ValidationGroup="LogonGroup" Columns="35" MaxLength="320"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredLogonEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextLogonEmail" ValidationGroup="LogonGroup" CssClass="error">required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
        </tr>
...
```

So, when you click on the login button, it would show the validation summary there.

Comment: where is the Page.Validate("LogonGroup") put?